# Update nested JSON with knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm attempting to alter a JSON in memory by using the knockout.js UI. The problem I'm running into is that when I alter a value in the UI, the JSON data doesn't seem to be changed whatsoever. I've implemented buttons with console.log(config) to test this. Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Hfwfs/1/

edit.js

```
var config = {

    "departments": [

    {
    "name": "Step Down"
    }, {
    "name": "ER"
    }]
};

var DepartmentViewModel = function (dep) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(dep.name);
}

function ConfigViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.departments = ko.observableArray([]);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(config.departments, function (dep) {
        self.departments.push(new DepartmentViewModel(dep));
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ConfigViewModel());
```

Comment: FYI: You don't have a "JSON object" (there's no such thing), you have a "JavaScript object".

Comment: Right--fixed my language.

Comment: What is it you're tying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a much, much larger nested javascript object that I'd like to be able to print to a UI dynamically and have each field manipulate the pertinent object data on-the-fly. It seems like the UI fields weren't directly linking to the original "config" javascript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is getting updated, you've to look in the model

[image]

Comment: Ok. So I'll just need to reassign my JSON "config" to the data within model? Is there any way around this, or is this the only way to edit a JSON on the fly?

Comment: To update a variable which is outside of the model (which is two-way bound) is complicated. You might end up making your own mvvm implementation if you look to that direction...for this case knockout.js pretty much satisfies your requirement.